# how can I connect, from a flask app, to a remote elasticsearch cluster on aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, flask

I have an elasticsearch cluster running on an EC2 server. I get a variety of different error mesages when I try to connect.

Currently, in the elasticsearch.yml file all the transport items are commented out but I have tried:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
and
network.host: ec2-xx-xxx-xxx.aws.instance.com
```

In my flask app the code is as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

#es = Elasticsearch()http://34.245.51.240/
es = Elasticsearch(['ec2-34-xxx-xx-240.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com','9200'])
#es = Elasticsearch(['34.245.51.240','9200'])

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    #results = es.get(index='contents', doc_type='title', id='my-new-slug')
    #return jsonify(results['_source'])
    doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
    }
    res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
    print(res['res'])
    return res


#application.run(port=5000, debug=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

I have googled multiple times and tried every possible configuration that I can find.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure the security groups on the ElasticSearch instance accepts incoming connections on port 9200 from your flask app.

Comment: thank you. I cannot find any specific "security group" items in the elasticsearch.yml file, I set host.port:0.0.0.0 apart from that I cannot see anything else I can do. Please could you be more specific?

Comment: The security group would be on the EC2 instance you are using to run ElasticSearch. Unless you are usinig ElasticSearch Service provided by AWS which does not look like that is the case.

Comment: Thanks good point. I will check and make sure it is set to 0.0.0.0 and report back.

Comment: that was not the problem. It was that there was no open port 9200. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help other people.

elasticsearch defaults to Port 9200 so it is necessary to open such a Port on the EC2 server as such:

```
CustomTCP TCP 9200 0.0.0.0
```

This is done by editing the security group wizard that set up security groups when you set up the server.

Then in your Python application the connection string is:

```
es = Elasticsearch("http://00.111.222.33")  //the public IP you can see on your EC2 dashboard
```

That's it. Hours of anguish and so simple.